# 3 columns return one value in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

3 columns to return a value in order and columns may not always have a value in it. 
Column 1 is primary.
Column 2 is secondary.
Column 3 is third. 
Column 4 is the returned value.

If column 1 has a value in it returns that value in column 4. 
If column 1 & 2 has a value in it returns column 1 value in column 4. 
If column 1 & 2 & 3 has a value in it returns column 1 value in column 4.

If column 2 has a value in it returns that value in column 4. 
If column 2 & 3 has a value in it returns column 2 value in column 4.

If column 3 has a value in it returns that value in column 4.

Can someone help with this for VBA coding? Or if an easier way of returning a value in column order. 
This is three columns that will have a Item#, Lab#, Developer# and the #s are letters and numbers. I want the Item# to show (if filled) or the Lab# to show (if filled) or the Dev# but in this order. Anyone can help?

Comment: I’m looking for someone to help with coding please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem can be solved in a query, using nested `IIf` statements:

```
SELECT 
    Col1, 
    Col2, 
    Col3, 
    IIf(Len([Col1])>0,[Col1],IIf(Len([Col2])>0,[Col2],IIf(Len([Col3])>0,[Col3],""))) AS SelectedData
FROM Table1;
```

This gives the following output:
[image]
Regards,

Comment: can you tell me the name of the software that you screenshot please? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the output of a query in Microsoft Access (hence this question being tagged "access-vba").

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "has a value in it" means not Null, the [Nz Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) can give you what you want if you nest them like this ...

```vb
Dim ReturnValue
ReturnValue = Nz(Col1, Nz(Col2, Col3))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does not always have a value in it.

Comment: Thank You I will try a query.